# Callback on serializer Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, serialization

I'm running Symfony 2.7 and I'm trying output an object (Doctrine entity) as JSON.

When I'm normalizing the object I want to convert some of it's values. To do this I found the "setCallbacks" method in [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#using-callbacks-to-serialize-properties-with-object-instances) but I'm kinda stumped on how to apply it to my case.

Is there any way to call the "setCallbacks" method on the normalizer that is set when calling Symfonys serializer service?

Here is a short example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
//ExampleController.php

public function getJSONOrderByIdAction($id) {
    $serializer = $this->get('serializer');
    $normalizer = $serializer->getNormalizer(); // <- This is what I'm unable to do

    $dateTimeToString = function ($dateTime) {
        return $dateTime instanceof \DateTime ? $dateTime->format(\DateTime::ISO8601) : '';
    };

    $normalizer->setCallbacks(['time' => $dateTimeToString]);


    $order = $this->getDoctrine()->find("AppBundle:Order", $id);

    return new JsonResponse(["order" => $serializer->normalize($order, null, ["groups" => ["public"]])]);
}
```

I'm aware that most people have switched to the JMS serializer. It just seems as if the built in serializer should be able to handle what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default Serializer service is created during dependency injection phase, and the Serializer interface do not allow editing of (full) retrieval of normalizers.

I think you have (at least) three choice here:

1. add your custom normalizer to the default Serializer service
2. add NormalizableInterface to your entities
3. create a new Serializer service (or a local object as suggested by the docs) as you were trying to do.

I think in your scenario, case 1 is preferred (since 2 becomes boring pretty fast).

I would do something like this; first create a custom Normalizer

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle; 

class DateTimeNormalizer extends SerializerAwareNormalizer implements NormalizerInterface, DenormalizerInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function normalize($object, $format = null, array $context = array())
    {
        return $object->format(\DateTime::ISO8601);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function denormalize($data, $class, $format = null, array $context = array())
    {
        return new $class($data);
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the given class is a DateTime.
     *
     * @param mixed  $data   Data to normalize.
     * @param string $format The format being (de-)serialized from or into.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function supportsNormalization($data, $format = null)
    {
        return $data instanceof \DateTime;
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the given class is a DateTime.
     *
     * @param mixed  $data   Data to denormalize from.
     * @param string $type   The class to which the data should be denormalized.
     * @param string $format The format being deserialized from.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function supportsDenormalization($data, $type, $format = null)
    {
        $class = new \ReflectionClass($type);

        return $class->isSubclassOf('\DateTime');
    }
}
```

Then register it to your services:

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    datetime_normalizer:
        class: AppBundle\DateTimeNormalizer
        tags:
            - { name: serializer.normalizer }
```

Comment: I haven't tested the code, but should work. Try it yourself and give me some feedback if needed; I will update the answer for the community

Comment: This looks like it might be the way to go.
The DateTime example was just what they used in Symfonys documentation - But let's say that my order has a collection of products and I need to do something with that aswell. Would I just create a ProductNormalizer or would I somehow need to handle the collection?

Also, I'm not entirely sure how to apply the new normalizers to the Symfony service? I take it that just creating the service isn't enough and the serializer doesn't seem to have a "addNormalizer" method.
I apologize if some of this should be a given. This is quite new territory for me.

Comment: @Daniel The default normalization process does it's best to give a default implementation, but default often translate to ugly. An 'addNormalizer' method is not there (for some good reason), but the tag 'serializer.normalizer' is there for you to use. You can have a generic `MyTweeksToNormalizer` class which handle multiple class, but this may become complex as you go. As an alternative, you can just implement `NormalizableInterface` to all your entity. As a better solution you can switch to `jms-serializer` and benefit of the configuration-driven serialization.

Comment: Applying NormalizableInterface to all entities is not an option since I need to be able to normalize the same object in a different number of ways. I'm starting to think that JMS serializer is indeed the way to go.  Thanks for the detailed answers.

Comment: @Daniel An "in-object" is always quick and easy, but less flexible. JMS serializer has "serialization context". By using different context, you can choose how and what to serialize, in different situation; and it all comes down to write `$serizalizer->serialize($object, 'my-context')`. Anyway, your're welcome! Just remember to +1 or accept if it helped ;)

Comment: Sounds promising. I had just hoped that the built in serializer was up for the task after they had updated it in 2.7. Sadly don't have enough points to +1 posts yet - But I accepted your answer :)

Comment: Symfony 3.1+ has DateTimeNormalizer

Answer (score 4):

**My own solution**

Following the advice from giosh94mhz I tried switching to JMS Serializer but ended up going back to Symfonys serializer.

JMS Serializer presented it's own issues and while searching for answers for those I stumbled upon a [blog post by Thomas Jarrand](http://thomas.jarrand.fr/blog/serialization/) that did an excellent job explaining how to make **and** implement your own normalizers in Symfony.

Answer (score 1):

You can use callback normalizer of K. Dunglas component.

You can see that in ObjectNormalizer (in normalize method)

```
if (isset($this->callbacks[$attribute])) {
    $attributeValue = call_user_func($this->callbacks[$attribute], $attributeValue);
 }
```

This mean that you must use in callback array key the name of property you wan't to normalize.

For example in my entity I have field named "name" of type "pgarray" (like array for postgresql). I wan't to normalize this data. Instead array I want a string.

```
/**
     * $object represent the property "name" because callback is attached to name property (setCallback)
     */
    $nameCallback = function ($object, $outerObject = null) {
        return $object[0];      
    };
    $this->normalizer->setCallbacks(['name' => $dateCallback]);
```

Just remember since Symfony 4.2 you must use $context in DI to use callback.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you seem to be trying to over-complicate things. Here's the approach I've taken when I needed to serialize my entities as JSON:

PHP 2.5 and above allows you to implement the [jsonSerialize](http://php.net/manual/en/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php) method on your objects and just call [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) directly on your object.

If you are still using PHP 2.4, you just need to manually call `jsonSerialize()` on your objects.

For example:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class MyEntity {
    ...
    public function jsonSerialize() {
        $data = array("foo" => $this->bar());
        // add other data here ...
        return $data
    }
}
```

And then in calling code:

```
// for PHP 2.5 and up:
$normalized = json_encode($myEntityInstance);

// for PHP 2.4 and below
$normalized = json_encode($myEntityInstance->jsonSerialize());
```

Comment: I would prefer to keep my entities as modular as possible. The current controller action has to transform the object in a certain way which would not be needed in other cases.

Comment: Oh, I see. Yes, you would not want to clutter the Entity class with non-standard serializations.