# symfony 3 normalizer for json - format all Timestamps

Tags: php, json, symfony

In my Symfony 3 app, I'm using a normalizer and a serializer to format a result set as JSON.  By default all the doctrine Datetimes are rendered in the format:

```
"maintenanceStart":{
 "timezone":{"name":"Australia\/Melbourne",
 "location":{"country_code":"AU","latitude":-37.81667,"longitude":144.96666,
 "comments":"Victoria"}},
 "offset":36000,"timestamp":1372892400}
```

I can output this in an ISO date format on a per-field basis by setting a callback on the normalizer as follows:

```
    $callback = function ($dateTime) {
        return $dateTime instanceof \DateTime ? $dateTime->format ( \DateTime::ISO8601 ) : '';
    };

    $normalizer->setCallbacks ( array (
            'maintenanceStart' => $callback 
    ) );
```

But I'd like to apply this change to *all* Timestamps without having to specify each field.  Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Entity definition:

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="MAINTENANCE_START", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private $maintenanceStart;
```

Controller code:

```
public function dataAction(Request $request) {

    $doc = $this->get ( 'doctrine' );
    $repo = $doc->getRepository ( 'AppBundle:Customer' );
    $result = $repo->createQueryBuilder ( 'c' )->getQuery ()->getResult ();

    $encoder = new JsonEncoder ();
    $normalizer = new GetSetMethodNormalizer ();

    $callback = function ($dateTime) {
        return $dateTime instanceof \DateTime ? $dateTime->format ( \DateTime::ISO8601 ) : '';
    };

    $normalizer->setCallbacks ( array (
            'maintenanceStart' => $callback 
    ) );

    $serializer = new Serializer ( array (
            $normalizer, new \AppBundle\DateTimeNormalizer() 
    ), array (
            $encoder 
    ) );

    $json = $serializer->serialize ( $result, 'json' );

    return $this->render ( 'default/data.json.twig', [ 
            'data' => $json,
            'base_dir' => realpath ( $this->getParameter ( 'kernel.root_dir' ) . '/..' ) 
    ] );
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In trying to follow the prescribed method (posted here  https://stackoverflow.com/a/33149890/403614), I neglected to observe that the Array of Normalizers passed into the Serializer is order-dependent.

So, the problem and fix for my code above is to reverse the order so that the DateTime Normalizer applies first:

```
$normalizer = new GetSetMethodNormalizer ();
$serializer = new Serializer ( array (
         new \AppBundle\DateTimeNormalizer(), $normalizer
), array (
        $encoder 
) );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own normalizer, and declare it as a service.

You can use the exact code of the response: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33149890/403614

Comment: I tried that, but on the line that tests `$data instanceof \DateTime`, it always returns false.  My date value appears as to be an Array of 4 values; `country_code`, `latitude`,`longitude` and `comments`

Comment: Have you tried to change the priority ? `- { name: serializer.normalizer, priority: 10 }`

Comment: @Francis Why are you using 4 parameters to change the timezone, you can just use Time Zone Abbreviations (one parameter). When you are inserting into the DB then you convert it into the timezone of the server. When you are displaying it to the user you can just change the global timezone of his preference. I hope this helps.

Comment: @PixelMaker I never intended for my Date/Time values to be represented in this Array form.  I used Doctrine to generate Model classes from an existing MySql database that uses MySql Timestamp for dates, and they come out in the Model classes in this Array format...