# How can i each a Json response with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, json, symfony

Good morning ,
I am programming with Symfony .
This is my Action :

```
public function selectcarsmonitorsAction($date) {
    $cars = array();
    $users= array();

    // Liste des voitures 
    $cars = $em->getRepository('ParcAutoBundle:Car')->FindAllCarsNotINCalendar($location, $date);

    // Liste des moniteurs
    $users= $em->getRepository('AuthenticationBundle:User')->FindAllUsersNotINCalendar($location, $date);

    foreach ($cars as $car) {
        $cars[] = $car->getId() . " " . $car->getMark() . " " . $car->getRegistrationnumber();
    }

    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $monitors[] = $user->getId() . " " . $user->getFirstname() . " " . $monitor->getLastname();
    }

    $response = new JsonResponse();
    $response->setData(array('cars' => $cars, 'users' => $users));

    return $response;
}
```

**First :** I don't know what's the underlined? Strange
[image]

**Second :** I want to put this in a select and option  ( a Select for cars and a select for Users).

thank you for your helps .

**EDIT 1 :**

How can i each this with JQUERY ??

[image]

Comment: Please have a look at the [manual on serialization](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#normalizers) and especially [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33148750/callback-on-serializer-symfony/33149890#33149890). Writing a custom Normalizer is not difficult and I would prefer it very much in this scenario (instead of doing the work in the controller)

Comment: i have serialized the cars and users with $carsserialized = $serializer->serialize($cars, 'json'); && $usersserialzed = $serializer->serialize($users, 'json'); you can see the pic in the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the each i putted Json.parse() :

```
   $.each(JSON.parse(cars), function (i, v) {
      selectcars += '<option value=' + v.id + '>' + v.mark + ' ' + v.registrationnumber + '</option>';
   });
   $('#cars').append(selectcars);
```

Answer (score 2):

second:

```
var select = $('#selectTag');
$.ajax({
    url: 'your_api',
    success: function(data) {
        var cars = data.cars;
        $.each(cars, function(index, item) {
            select.append($('<option>'), {
                value: xxx,
                text: xxx
            }));
        });
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(url, status, err.toString());
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you explain to the OP (in your answer), why `$list` (or even `$listCars`) will solve this?

Comment: i misunderstand the first question.. @kero's comment should do the thing

Comment: Thank you for your response .. but what i put in the 'xxx' .. i want in the value the id of car and in the text the mark and registration number ??